# Jasper report server Global Variable

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

In Jasper Report Server is there any way to have the global variables, such as set  queries/jrxml must be assigned with a value and another set when executed get different values for same variable. 
So that we can use single query/jrxml to provide multiple results based on the value assigned to it on execution. 
How to use a variable like that?

Comment: if I understand correctly then you are looking for reusability of JasperReports i.e. you could have differently types of report (with same layout) displayed dynamically based on some switch (like input from user). Am I understanding correct?

Comment: yes @Siddharth , exactly it is for reusability